# iOS: What are the steps to upgrading an iPad app?

Tags: ios, upgrade

I'm a Ruby on Rails developer trying to learn iOS and Xcode. I was recently given the task to upgrade a iPad app to the latest version. It's a bit difficult trying to find tutorials on how to do that, since most posts are from the user perspective (how to upDATE apps through iTunes or whatever).

My big question is: What are the steps in upgrading a iPad app? I believe the current version it is written in is using Xcode 4.2 (not sure if that's relevant) and iOS 4.3. And the target version is 6.x. Would I just upgrade to 5, and then upgrade to 6 from there? Is there documentation on the changes between those versions and were they large enough to make the upgrade process troublesome?

Comment: This question is way to broad and vague to solicit a meaningful answer.

Comment: please clear your requirements first from your senior or from client, and specify the proper details i.e previous app version and target ios etc...

Comment: The question has been updated

Comment: most of the time, you can just recompile with the latest version and fix anything that might not work as expected

Comment: Like Mike said, test it on desired version and you will find what you need to fix..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should try to compile the app with the new iOS version. 
Most of the time it works great.

Reference the documentation, there are two different documents:

1. The API Difference document, which shows the difference between one iOS version and the one before. [API Diffference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS61APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012875)
2. The What's new document is a "list" of the differences in general. [What's new](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008246)